# how to make Android App Bundle with Adobe Animate to publish it to google store?

Tags: publishing

How to create an "Android App Bundle" instead of an APK when using adobe animate.
To publish Android apps on Google platform, we need to create an App Bundle instead of creating an APK, and that has annoyed many app developers who use adobe animate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate-discussions/androin-app-bundle/td-p/12089313